# Column header shows arrow icon after sortable is false in ExtJs grid

Tags: sorting, extjs, gridpanel

I have an ExtJs GridPanel in which sortable is false in all the columns.

Then if I sort store by

```
this.store.sort('Column1','ASC');
```

then the arrow reappers .

Does sortable gets true?
Is this because I am sorting the store or anything else?

If it the reason different than that then what is the solution for removing the arrow?

I would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arrow is being shown because of the sorter in the store, which identifies a column in the grid which has the dataIndex equal to the property you are sorting, despite the sorting being disable on this column. In this case, you could override the [getSortParam](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-method-getSortParam) function in your column definition, like this:

```
getSortParam: Ext.emptyFn
```

And your column will no longer show the arrow in the header.